# How to printout a single line at time according to a schedule from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, scheduled-tasks, java-threads

I am trying to create a method that prints out a single line at a time, with two minutes delay between. How do I do that?.

This part of the code reads a text file (questionsFile) and creates an ArrayList:

```
public Broadcaster(Socket connection) throws IOException {

    read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    write = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());  

    List<String> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> questionsStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(questionsFile))) {
        questionsList = questionsStream
                .parallel()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException w) {
        w.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here bellow there is a timer but for some reason, I can't make it work. The whole ArrayList is printed out with no delay what so ever. My intention is to use a printStream but for testing purposes, the text is currently printed out to the console. How can the code be rewritten so it prints out a single line at a time?

```
    List<String> finalQuestionsList = questionsList; 
    timer.schedule(task(() -> finalQuestionsList.forEach(System.out::println))
            , 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
}

private TimerTask task(Runnable task) {
    return new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();
```

Comment: did you ever call timer.start()?
is the timer set to be recurring?

Comment: Not directly, but the I am starting up the method with a ExecutorService which makes everything run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trivial solution would be:

```
for (String question : questionsList) {
    timer.schedule(task(() -> System.out.println(question)), 0);
    try {
        sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course, it’s ridiculous to use a `Timer` when this loop blocks the thread via `sleep` anyway. With this code, the timer is entirely obsolete. This code even waits two seconds after the last element has been printed…

Comment: You're right. I wanted to stay as close to the original code from the question as possible. And also wrote "The trivial solution: